# Tracking number of downloads a file without hit

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, download, tracking

I don't have access to the server. Is there anyway that I can count the number of downloads of a .zip file without counting the number of hits on a link?
For example by copy/paste this URL, [URL.com/file.zip](http://khordokalan.ir), the file will be downloaded directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use url shortener such as Google url shortner(https://goo.gl/#)